# Media Query why isnt my code not being accepted ie doesnt work

Tags: css, media

When resizing the browser none of the code below works

i also already have the style content before the @media content. i have no idea i ve tried everything already. but its just not working
I used MAC google chrome.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Responsive Web Design</title>
<meta name= "viewport" content="width=device-width">    

 <link href="responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">    


<!-- css down below -->


@media screen and (max-width: 720px;){
nav ul{
max-height: 0;
}


nav ul li {
  box-sizing: border-box ;
  width:100%;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;}

.handle { display:block;
```

Comment: Create JSFiddle for this

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/99xqdgtn/

Comment: Updated https://jsfiddle.net/99xqdgtn/1/

Comment: nothings changed still not working?

Answer (score 1):

```
Always write the Media Queries like this do not use semicolon(;) after declaring your width in media syntax

Example:

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    /*Responsive code goes here */
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
/*Responsive code goes here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is this semicolon after 720px:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 720px;)
```

You have to delete:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 720px)
```